# Xamarin iOS Framework Binding

Tags: xamarin, mono, xamarin.ios, cocoapods, objective-sharpie

I am trying to create a binding for the WePay Framework:
https://github.com/wepay/wepay-ios

Following are the steps that I followed.

1. I installed CocoaPods.
2. I installed ObjectiveSharpie
3. I run this command in terminal : `$ sharpie pod init ios WePay`

And I get this error: Could not install CocoaPod

here is the full error message:

```
** Setting up CocoaPods master repo ...
```

(this may take a while the first time)
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
  $ /usr/bin/git pull --ff-only
  From https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs
     ee36ba4..8c6767d  master     -> origin/master
  Updating ee36ba4..8c6767d
  Fast-forward
   Specs/BluetoothKit/0.3.0/BluetoothKit.podspec.json | 35 ++++++++++++++++++++++
   1 file changed, 35 insertions(+)
   create mode 100644 Specs/BluetoothKit/0.3.0/BluetoothKit.podspec.json
Setup completed
** Searching for requested CocoaPods ...
** Working directory: 
**   - Writing Podfile ...
**   - Installing CocoaPods ...
**     (running `pod install --no-integrate --no-repo-update`)
[!] Unknown option: `--no-integrate`
Did you mean: --no-ansi?

Usage:

```
$ pod install

  Downloads all dependencies defined in `Podfile` and creates an Xcode Pods
  library project in `./Pods`.

  The Xcode project file should be specified in your `Podfile` like this:

      project 'path/to/XcodeProject.xcodeproj'

  If no project is specified, then a search for an Xcode project will be
  made. If more than one Xcode project is found, the command will raise an
  error.

  This will configure the project to reference the Pods static library, add
  a build configuration file, and add a post build script to copy Pod
  resources.
```

Options:

```
--repo-update                       Force running `pod repo update` before
                                    install
--project-directory=/project/dir/   The path to the root of the project
                                    directory
--silent                            Show nothing
--verbose                           Show more debugging information
--no-ansi                           Show output without ANSI codes
--help                              Show help banner of specified command
```

error: could not install CocoaPod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well apparently the most recent CocoaPods removed the --no-integrate option that objective sharpie uses. Downgrading cocoapods to 0.39.0 should fix your issue. It worked for us.

Comment: Thank you that helped. Thought I also had to downgrade ruby to 2.2.0 get it working.

Comment: Well apparenlty, as of ObjectiveSharpie 3.1, this issue should be fixed
See: [link]http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/67908/objective-sharpie-3-1